# How do i position a lightbox/div popup so that it comes in the center of the viewport in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, positioning, prototypejs

How do i position a lightbox/div popup so that it comes in the center of the viewport in an iframe.

The iframe is embedded into a HTML from a different domain.

Answer (score 0):

All changes below are referring to the page being loaded in the iframe.

First, add the div to the bottom of the body of your document.

```
var body = $('body')[0];
$(body).append("<div id='modal' style='position:absolute;display:none;'></div>");
```

Then when you want to use the modal, run the following code (within a function):

```
// to position it, do the following
var body = $('body')[0];

// get the position and size info on the iframe
var height = $(body).height();
var width = $(body).width();

// get the size information on the modal div
var divHeight = $('#modal').height();
var divWidth = $('#modal').width();

// put it together to get the proper position
var top = (height/2)-(divHeight/2);
var left = (width/2)-(divWidth/2);

// set it and we're done, hiya!
$('#modal').css('top', top);
$('#modal').css('left', left);

// show the div
$('#modal').css('display', 'block');
```

**Note two things**

1. You should add the modal div to the body element to make life easier
2. The modal should have a position of absolute - in the example I put it inline

Give that a shot :)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply. The problem here is that my javascript is not running in the parent document. It is running inside the iframe's document. So I need a way to find an offset of the iframe (just as you mentioned) but through the code which is present inside the iframe. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then it is the same as centering a modal on a regular page. I'll update the reply.